# Rectifying SOAP exception with java

Tags: java, soap

Below is how I am calling my webservice via this code snippet below.

```
  try{
             SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
             SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
             String url = "http://**********/webservice.asmx?WSDL";
             SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(soapCalling(dataID,dataString), url);
             printSOAP(soapACK,dataID);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
```

I keep getting error. Does the error reflect the server is down or any other hints on this? What is be best rectification on this? Is it necessary to add   soapConnection .setConnectTimeout (30 * 1000);      // 15 sec
                 soapConnection .setReadTimeout (30 * 1000);

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl identifyContentType
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
at cs1$cr1.sendIncomingData(cs1.java:2829)
at cs1$cr1r.run(cs1.java:2454)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
```

Comment: Could it be your URL is returning the WSDL instead of actually calling the web service?  Maybe try removing "?WSDL"

Comment: No it have been working fine only recently when the web service is down I get all this errors

Comment: So wait, you are surprised that there are errors calling a webservice when its down?

Comment: Yes I am not sure is it due to the webservice being down or due other factor is not where I am confused?

Comment: You might try using SoapUI to connect directly to the web service and see what it's returning.  Also you can add logging on the Java side to display what it's returning as well.  It might be a generic error page served up by the application server.

Comment: Where should I add the logging in which section of the codes? What do you mean by generic error page ?